# Python regex problem when using the sub() method to replace content in html code to respective translations

Tags: python, regex

I am a beginner at Python and met with some coding problem that I can't solve.

**What I have:**

the source sentences and their respective translations in two columns in a spreadsheet;

the html code which contains sentences and html tags

**What I'm trying to do:** use Python regex method - sub() to find and replace english sentences to their respective translated sentences.

**For example:** three sentences in html codes -
*Pumas are large animals.
They are found in America.
They don't eat grass*

I have the translations of each sentence in the html code. I want to replace the sentences one at a time and also keep the html tags. Normally I can use the sub() method like this:

```
regex1 = re.compile(r'(\>.*)SOURCE_SENTENCE_HERE ?(.*\<)')

resultCode = regex1.sub(r'\1TRANSLATION_SENTENCE_HERE\2', originalHtmlCode)
```

I've written a python script to do this. I save the html code in a txt file and access it in my Python code (**succeeded**). Then I create a dictionary to store the source-target paires in the spreadsheet mentioned above (**succeeded**). Lastly, I use rexgex sub() method to find and replace the sentences in the html code (**failed**). This last part didn't work at all for some reason. Link to **my Python code** - https://pastebin.com/ZSUNB4yg or below:

```
import re, openpyxl, pyperclip

buynavFile = open('C:\\Users\\zs\\Documents\\PythonScripts\\buynavCode.txt')
buynavCode = buynavFile.read()
buynavFile.close()

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('buynavSegments.xlsx')              
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')                          
segDict = {}
maxRow = sheet.max_row
for i in range(2, maxRow + 1):
    segDict[sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value] = sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value

for k, v in segDict.items():                            
    k = '(\\>.*)' + str(k) + ' ?(.*\\<)'                
    v = '\\1' + str(v) + '\\2'                          
    buynavRegex = re.compile(k)
    buynavResult = buynavRegex.sub(v, buynavCode)

pyperclip.copy(buynavResult)                            
print('Result copied to clipboard')
```

**Error message** below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\zs\Documents\PythonScripts\buynav.py", line 20, in
>
> buynavResult = buynavRegex.sub(v, buynavCode)
>
> File "C:\Users\zs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\re.py",
> line 326, in _subx
>
> template = _compile_repl(template, pattern)
>
> File "C:\Users\zs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\re.py",
> line 317, in _compile_repl
>
> return sre_parse.parse_template(repl, pattern)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\zs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\sre_parse.py",
> line 943, in parse_template
>
> addgroup(int(this[1:]), len(this) - 1)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\zs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\sre_parse.py",
> line 887, in addgroup
>
> raise s.error("invalid group reference %d" % index, pos)
>
> sre_constants.error: invalid group reference 11 at position 1

Could someone enlighten me on this please? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Note that `buynavResult` is getten overwritten, not appended to, in each loop.  Also, I would consider traversing the DOM with something like lxml rather than using regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider if you want to use a replacement text where you have to put the contents of group 1 and concatenate them to the string `2`. You could write `r'\12'` but this wont work because the regex parser will think that you are referencing group `12` instead of the group `1` followed by the string `2`!

```
>>> re.sub(r'(he)llo', r'\12', 'hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 191, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 326, in _subx
    template = _compile_repl(template, pattern)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 317, in _compile_repl
    return sre_parse.parse_template(repl, pattern)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 943, in parse_template
    addgroup(int(this[1:]), len(this) - 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 887, in addgroup
    raise s.error("invalid group reference %d" % index, pos)
sre_constants.error: invalid group reference 12 at position 1
```

You can solve this using the `\g<1>` syntax to refer to the group: `r'\g<1>2'`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(he)llo', r'\g<1>2', 'hello')
'he2'
```

In your case your replacement string contains dynamic contents like `str(v)` which can be anything. If it happens to start with a number you end up in the case described before so you want to use `\g<1>` to avoid this issue.